# How to add new keys to an empty dictionary as it goes/reads through an input list?

Tags: python

I would like to add new keys to an empty dictionary as it goes/reads through my list.

I got this to work when I used a list containing only numbers. However, if I try this with a list which contains strings and numbers I get a KeyError for the first string in the list.

Could anyone maybe tell me why this is, or how I can fix it?

```
di = {}
stuff = ['sun', 20, 20, 14.3, 'sun', 'Flower']
for thing in stuff:
    if thing not in stuff:
        di[thing] = 1
    else:
        di[thing] += 1
print(di)
```

Comment: The key for a dictionary can be any immutable object, so using a number or a string should be fine. Without seeing your code we can't find out where you made an error. Please show your code (a minimized but runnable example that comes up with the error).

Comment: @Vic: Please edit the question and add the code there.

Comment: According to the code you had in the comments you should replace `if thing not in stuff:` by `if thing not in di:`. You're checking the source list at the moment.

Comment: I don’t understand this code at all. You’re looping over stuff list, but you have a condition to check if the element you’re looping over isn’t in the stuff list? That doesn’t make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

You're checking for the existence of `thing` in your list, not in your dictionary.

```
di = {}
stuff = ['sun', 20, 20, 14.3, 'sun', 'Flower']
for thing in stuff:  # error was here
    if thing not in di:
        di[thing] = 1
    else:
        di[thing] += 1
print(di)
```

Are you aware of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)? `Counter` is a subclass of `dict` that can do the counting for you.

```
from collections import Counter
di = Counter(stuff)
print(di)
```

Your approach is fine if you're still learning, but using `Counter` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If the task is strictly counting the occurrences then `collections.Counter()` is the way to go (as @matthias recommends).

A more general way to build a dictionary when you need to alter the key values as you go and where the key may or may not exists is to use the companion `collections.defaultdict()` or the built in dictionary `setdefault()`.

Your code using `setdefault()` might look a bit like:

```
stuff = ['sun', 20, 20, 14.3, 'sun', 'Flower']

di = {}
for thing in stuff:
    di[thing] = di.setdefault(thing, 0) + 1

print(di)
```

I want to stress though that if you are just looking to count the occurrences of items in a list, `collections.Counter()` is the way to go and the answer by @matthias is what you want to accept.

Comment: Getting rid of the `if`-`else` is good, but I wouldn't use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) but [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). With `di[thing] = ...` you're going to (re)create an entry in the dictionary anyway, so this additional task of `setdefault` isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

counter = defaultdict(int)
stuff = ['sun', 20, 20, 14.3, 'sun', 'Flower']
for s in stuff:
  counter[s] +=1 
print(counter)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'sun': 2, 20: 2, 14.3: 1, 'Flower': 1})
```