# This produces and empty dictionary, and I don't know why

Tags: python

this is the start of something I'm trying to do as a weekly TAFE worksheet. All it requires is the emails sent in the text file to be tallied up and see who sent the most emails. Still quite new to all of it so sorry if noob question. This seems to me like it should grab the email addresses on each relevant line in the file and add it as a key to the dictionary.

```
if len(fname) < 1:
    fname = "mbox-short.txt"
fhand = open(fname)
frequency = dict()
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith("From "):
        line = line.split()
        frequency.get(line[1], 0) + 1
print(frequency)
```

Comment: You are never storing anything in your dictionary.

Comment: This is a good use-case for [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples). See the example for "*Setting the default_factory to int makes the defaultdict useful for counting*"

Comment: Duplicate of: [I would like to add new keys to an empty dictionary as it goes/reads through my list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69688380/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

You should add something to the dictionary, but your code is not doing that. Consider to do this:

```
if len(fname) < 1:
    fname = "mbox-short.txt"
fhand = open(fname)
frequency = dict()
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith("From "):
        line = line.split()
        frequency[line[1]] = frequency.get(line[1], 0) + 1
print(frequency)
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you! I see now that calling the get function doesn't apply the changes to the dictionary on its own.

Comment: Yeah, `get` method of `dict` object doesn't change dictionary itself, but returning a value (or default second parameter) More information here: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20get#dict.get